# tinn-r 2.4.1.5 does not pass zoomplot

Tags: tinn-r

I recenty installed R 3.0.0 passing the commands through Tinn R 2.4.1.5

I tried to use the function zoomplot(locator) from TeachingDemos

I got the error below:

> Error in .Primitive(".External2")(c(2799.10559440559, 2848.00769230769,  : 
>    first argument must be a string (of length 1) or native symbol reference

Interstingly enough, everything else being equal the function works fine with Tinn-R 1.7

I am running R on a Windows XP 32.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Best wishes,

Heriberto

Answer (score 0):

Did you try: zoomplot(locator(n)) , where n is the number of point that you want select